# Lego EV3 not Executing programs

Tags: eclipse, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

I have been working on this project since September and I have a presentation next week! Everything was working fine until today!

No matter what I try to run on the EV3 it just beeps and gives an error:

> Uncaught exception:
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
> move : Unsupported MajorMinor

I have tried re installing the plug in and I have tried using an older JRE so im really stuck and in a panic.

The program I am trying to run at the moment is simply moving the two motors, I have even tried a simple 'hello world' program but nothing runs.

Answer (score 0):

There was another version of OpenCV in the library. If any one else gets this error it may be worth checking all the installs and libraries